# How to post json data to a php script with $http.post

Tags: javascript, php, json, angularjs

I've been having this problem for a while and tried many solutions which haven't worked.
I am trying to use $http.post to send json data to a php script named processCustomers.php which is part of my API

The post request is

```
angular.extend(obj, {id: id});
  $http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: '../API/processCustomers.php',
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    dataType: 'json',
    data: obj
   }).success(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
};
```

and the processCustomers is

```
$newCustomers = filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'newCustomer');
if ($newCustomers) {#request to add new customer

    $exceptionalFields = ['customerID']; //

    $customersJSON = json_decode(filter_input(INPUT_POST, "newCustomer"));



    if (json_last_error() > 0) {
        echo DotCom::systemFeedBack("Sorry customer not created unknown error", "data sent is not a json object", 303);
        return;
    }



    foreach ($customersJSON as $key => $customer) {
        $parameterTypes = ""; # order determined by the sql returned by validateInputData()


    $entries = $func->validateInputData($tableMetaData,$customer, $parameterTypes, $exceptionalFields);


    if (!is_array($entries)) {
        echo $entries;
        return;
    }

     $results = $customers->createCustomer($entries, $parameterTypes, $link,$status);
```

When I send the request, the console in the browser says the response is text/html instead of application/json.I looked through many tutorials and examples and I also have tried the folowings:
removing the headers and datatype - no effect
wrapping the obj in JSON.stringify - results in header changing to application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Comment: what is the issue...receiving in php or receiving in client?

Comment: I don't know much about PHP, but you said your response that you are getting back is of type `text\html` so did you try setting up contenttype in php like `header('Content-Type: application/json');` ?

Answer (score 1):

You need the following in your php file:

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
```

`$_POST` will be empty when `Content-Type: application/json` is passed in headers.

Learned few days back from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004783/reading-json-post-using-php) questions