# Differences between PHP's $_POST and $_GET with AngularJS client side

Tags: php, json, angularjs, post

I was trying to pass JSON to a PHP script in AngularJS, like so:

```
var testObj = {
  answers : {
    aa : 2,
    ab : 3
  }
};

var userAnswers = angular.toJson(testObj.answers);

$http.post("ajax/testAddObject.php?answers=" + userAnswers).
success(function(data){
    console.log("Result: ", data);
});
```

On the PHP side I was doing the following:

```
//... new PDO connection to DB
$answers = $_POST['answers'];

//some more stuff
```

The `$answers` variable was always empty. But then, almost randomly, I saw [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30229644/how-to-post-json-data-to-a-php-script-with-http-post) and the answer said:

> `$_POST` will be empty when `Content-Type: application/json` is passed in headers

And, although my code was not exactly like the one from the question, I changed the `$_POST[...]` to `$_GET[...]` on the PHP code and it worked! **Question is, why**? What is the difference between one another? Because, from what I saw, there seems to be no big difference...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/504947/when-should-i-use-get-or-post-method-whats-the-difference-between-them will provide some insight, as well as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/46585/when-do-you-use-post-and-when-do-you-use-get

Comment: This is also a useful link for reading about the workings of GET/POST : http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/http-headers-for-dummies--net-8039

Comment: Thanks a lot @Martin! already taking a look at them

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`$http.post("ajax/testAddObject.php?answers=" + userAnswers).`

Here you are sending `answers` as query parameters (GET) to `testAddObject.php` and not posting them (POST) - note the `?` parameter at the end of `testAddObject.php` -

$_GET datas are passed as parameters in a URL. $_POST are not.

Comment: He isnt even really using the post request it just hits the url with a parameter in the query string so it is possible to use get

Comment: That's why he gets nothing using $_POST as the parameter is not `posted` but added to url. You know that and I also.

Comment: Yeah, I understand that now, also. I'm kinda noob in this particular topic.. Let me just ask you, then: if I did `$http.post("ajax/testAddObject.php", {answers : userAnswers})` then `$_POST['answers']` would work?

Comment: I never worked with angular js but related to the angular js documentation, your code should work.

Answer (score 4):

`$_POST` is populated with data from the body of the HTTP request if that data is formatted using one of the [multipart](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#multipart-form-data) or [url-encoded](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#url-encoded-form-data) formats.

`$_GET` is populated with data from the [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) portion of the URL.

`$_GET` will be populated even if the request wasn't a GET request. It only cares if it was in the query string or not.

---

Since it was brought up in the comments. `$_REQUEST` contains the data from `$_POST` **and** the data from `$_GET` **and** the data from `$_COOKIES`. It's generally best avoided as it makes it possible to be surprised by data coming from places you don't expect.

Comment: "$_GET will be populated even if the request wasn't a GET request" You wanna say `$_REQUEST` no ?

Comment: @zeflex — No. I meant `$_GET`. `$_REQUEST` is different.

Answer (score 0):

I dug a little deeper into the problem and I found [this article](http://serebrov.github.io/html/2013-05-24-angular-post-to-php.html) that explains that this kinda is an AngularJS "feature", actually.

> By default angular.js sends all data in json. So if you do a `POST` request to a PHP code then the `$_POST` superglobal will not be populated.

Although my code was not the completely right, if I change the client side to:

```
$http.post("ajax/testAddObject.php?", {answers : userAnswers}) //...
```

and change the PHP accordingly, the `$_POST[...]` still returns nothing, which makes some sense now.

According to the same article there are two solutions, one on the client side and another on the server side

> On the server you can parse input and then decode data from json:
>
> ```
> $data = file_get_contents("php://input");
> $postData = json_decode($data);`
> ```
>
> On the client side the data can be sent in a way PHP expects it:
>
> ```
> $http({
>     url:url
>     data : $.param(data),
>     method : 'POST',
>     headers : {'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8'}
> }).success(callback);
> ```