# AngularJS HTTP POST

Tags: javascript, ajax, angularjs

I have a php page, `submit.php`, that takes the "data" parameter, `get` or `post`, and shoves it into a local file; I know it works because I tested it with jQuery using `$.ajax`. However, I need to use AngularJS for this app. When I try this:

```
$http.post("submit.php", {"data": "foobar"});
```

nothing happens; the output file is unchanged. What am I doing wrong? How am I supposed to send the post request? It shows up in my chrome console as a post request, with the data I gave it, and yet has no effect on the file. Meanwhile,

```
$.post('submit.php', {'data': 'barfoo'});
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open your developer tools. Open the Net tab. Run your Angular code. Run the jQuery code. Look at the request in the developer tools. Compare them.

Then see the manuals:

From the [Angular manual](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses):

> If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format.

From the [jQuery manual](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> By default, data passed in to the data option as an object (technically, anything other than a string) will be processed and transformed into a query string, fitting to the default content-type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded".

PHP doesn't parse JSON formatted request bodies automatically.

Either:

- Change the PHP to [parse JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004783/reading-json-post-using-php)
- Change your Angular calling code to [use a different transform function](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#transforming-requests-and-responses)

Comment: Ah, I see. So, should I do something like `$.post('submit.php', "{'data': 'barfoo'}");` ?

Comment: Nvm, didn't see that you'd added a link.