# Pull values from: {"attending":0,"eventid":1,"userid":1} in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

So far I've tried a couple of methods for pulling the data from the following array that is received from JAVA(After print_r($_POST)):

```
{"attending":0,"eventid":1,"userid":1}
```

But I am having no luck, as other ways I've found on SO and around the net are all slightly different (Surrounded by ' ' and [])

**My code:**

```
print_r($_POST);
$data = json_decode($_POST);

$userid = $data['userid'];
$eventid = $data['eventid'];
$attending = $data['attending'];
```

My question is: how do I correctly pull the values from the Post and assign them to values?

I'm new to PHP so please no rude comments.

I have also tried:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST, true);
```

As mentioned in the comments but now I get:

```
Warning: json_decode() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in C:\xampp\htdocs\attendanceradio.php on line 9
```

**var_dump($_POST);:**

```
Array
                                                          (
                                                              [{"attending":0,"eventid":2,"userid":1}] => 
                                                          )
                                                          array(1) {
                                                            ["{"attending":0,"eventid":2,"userid":1}"]=>
                                                            string(0) ""
                                                          }
```

**Full PHP code:**

```
<?php

    $user = 'root';
    $pass = '';
    $db = 'testuser';

    $con=mysqli_connect('localhost', $user, $pass, $db) or die('Unable to connect');
    print_r($_POST['json']);
    var_dump($_POST);

    $json = json_decode(trim(key($_POST), '[]'), true);
        var_dump($json);
    $userid = $json['userid'];
    $eventid = $json['eventid'];
    $attending = $json['attending'];

    $statement = mysqli_prepare($con, 
    'INSERT INTO user_has_event(user_user_id, event_event_id, attendance)
        VALUES (?, ?, ?)
        ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attendance = ?');

    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'iii', $userid, $eventid, $attending);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);

    mysqli_stmt_store_result($statement);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_result($statement, $userid, $eventid, $attending);

    mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

    mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Comment: If you want to use the decoded value as an array you'll need to do : `json_decode($_POST, true)`

Comment: @PaulCrovella I dont think that it is a duplicate as the answers to that question is what I already have in my code. I'm clearly having a different problem.

Comment: @PaulCrovella I've already read that page before posting my question, else I wouldn't have asked. I mentioned that I was new to PHP, Could you please be more constructive?

Comment: @DarkBee could you please check my edit?

Comment: could you make a var_dump($_POST); and tell me the result? I will help you

Comment: @Kangoo13 Check the edit

Comment: `$_POST` is an array. `json_decode` expects a string, I guess. Access the array via `$_POST["data"]` or whatever the json-part of the post data is called. Try `$data = json_decode($_POST["data"]);`

Comment: As @jDo said it's an array that's why I wanted you to see with var_dump you can see from which index of the array the value is in.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Reading JSON POST using PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004783/reading-json-post-using-php)

Comment: It looks like the JSON string is the *key* of the `$_POST` array element, instead of the value??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your data something like the following should work?

```
<?php

$json = json_decode(trim(key($_POST), '[]'), true);

var_dump($json);

?>
```

Comment: That could have done it, Just having problems with bind variables now. Once that is sorted I can be sure: `Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement`. I posted my full code in case you wanted to take a look at it.

Comment: your mysqli_stmt_bind_param has an extra parameter 'iiii' not sure why that is there so you are binding 4 params rather than the 3 in the query

Comment: Do you mean the 4th: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE attendance = ?`?

Comment: mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'iiii', $userid, $eventid, $attending, $attending);

Comment: Yes you have 4 parameters defined so you have to add an extra type 'iiii' (4) and a duplicate $attending parameter, i assume you will have to do the same for your results aswell

Comment: Thanks for spending your time helping me out, I really appreciate it! It looks like I'm making slow progress now. Duplicating $attendance worked for the param and now I only get the warning for the result: `Warning: mysqli_stmt_bind_result(): Number of bind variables doesn't match number of fields in prepared statement in C:\xampp\htdocs\attendanceradio.php on line 27`(with 3 or 4 paramaters). Is there any way that I can know what is expected?

Comment: I forgot you are doing an insert statement which means that you are not returning any results so you dont need to bind the results if you were doing a select col1, col2, col3 from table where ... then you would need to bind the results into variables but in this case this is not required so you can just remove this line

Comment: Perfect, looks like its working properly now. I'll have to edit my JAVA slightly but I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

The error message that Array was given instead of a string and according to the var_dump I can see that POST is returning an array.

If you want to decode the JSON string you have to point to add the array index where the string is located, so your code should look like:

```
$data = json_decode($_POST[0], true);

$userid = $data['userid'];
$eventid = $data['eventid'];
$attending = $data['attending'];
```

Comment: With that I get `Notice: Undefined offset: 0 in C:\xampp\htdocs\attendanceradio.php on line 12`, almost ready to give PHP up all together!