# Axios posting params not read by $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, reactjs, axios

So I have this code:

```
axios({
    method: 'post',
    url,
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' },
    data: {
        json,
        type,
    }   
})
```

Originally I had the normal `axios.post` but I changed to this because I thought it might have been a header problem. However I am still detecting nothing in my `$_REQUEST` nor `$_POST`. However, it is receiving data in `file_get_contents("php://input")`.

Any idea what is wrong?

**Edit**

Okay I think I know what's wrong. It's posting it as a json object so it can only be read in the php://input. How do I change it to a normal string in axios?

Comment: if you remove the headers does it still not detected?

Comment: No, I think it's because of the way axios's post works, which it just passes a json object. I just tried their get version and it works as expected.

Comment: Show us how you declare "json" and "type" variables

Comment: @Borjante Not the problem as it works with the `get` method

Comment: If anyone writing their own MVC framework in PHP as well and runs into this problem: just decode it as json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true) instead of trying to access the $_POST variable

Answer (score 74, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format) (I haven't preserved links in the quoted material):

> ## Using application/x-www-form-urlencoded format
>
> By default, axios serializes JavaScript objects to JSON.

PHP doesn't support JSON as a data format for populating `$_POST`.

It only supports the machine-processable formats [natively supported by HTML forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form#attr-enctype):

- application/x-www-form-urlencoded
- multipart/form-data

> To send data in the application/x-www-form-urlencoded format instead, you can use
> one of the following options.
>
> ### Browser
>
> In a browser, you can use the URLSearchParams API as follows:
>
> ```
> var params = new URLSearchParams();
> params.append('param1', 'value1');
> params.append('param2', 'value2');
> axios.post('/foo', params);
> ```
>
> Note that URLSearchParams is not supported by all browsers, but there
> is a polyfill available (make sure to polyfill the global
> environment).
>
> Alternatively, you can encode data using the qs library:
>
> ```
> var qs = require('qs');
> axios.post('/foo', qs.stringify({ 'bar': 123 }));
> ```

Or you could customise your PHP so it can handle JSON as per [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19007851/19068) on another question.

Comment: For me it worked with `var params = new FormData();` instead of `URLSearchParams()`.

Comment: @Palantir — That sends multipart data not URL encoded data (which the question was attempting to send)

Answer (score 56):

```
var params = {
    data1: 'string',
}

axios.post(url, params).then(function(response) {
    //code here 
});
```

or

```
axios.post(url, {data1: 'string' }).then(function(response) {
    //code here 
});
```

api

```
$_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
echo $_POST['data1'];
```

Comment: may-2021 and still a simple and effective solution!

Comment: There's no way to get axiom to do it properly? I don't want to have to put code on every page, when axiom is doing it wrong.

Answer (score 12):

To make things easier and universal if you ever decided to switch between `AJAX` libraries or server languages. With `axios` use the native JS `FormData`.
If you have your data in an object, you can convert it to `FormData` like this:

```
var myDataObj = {id:1, name:"blah blah"}
var formData = new FormData();


for (var key in myDataObj) {
    formData.append(key, myDataObj[key])
}
```

Then you send the data:

```
axios.post('/sub/process.php', formData, {
    params: { action: "update-user" },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' },
    baseURL: 'http://localhost',
}).then(data =>
    console.log(data)
).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    return null
})
```

Notice, you can also send some info using `params` in `axios` that you can retrieve using `$_GET`. Also notice that I am using the baseURL in case you have different servers for the web page and your API endpoint.
You need to understand also that before `axios` send the real request, it performs a `preflight` request. [A preflight request, is a mechanism in CORS by the browser to check if the resource destination is willing to accept the real request or not. Afterall, why would a request be sent when the target host is not willing to receive it anyway?](https://dev.to/p0oker/why-is-my-browser-sending-an-options-http-request-instead-of-post-5621)

You have to make sure that your server has the right headers for your axios request, otherwise the preflight request will detect the incompatibility and stop your request:

```
//this is if you are using different different origins/servers in your localhost, * to be update with the right address when it comes to production
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
//this is if you are specifying content-type in your axios request
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");
```

Now, you will able to access your sent data in the `$_POST` variable:

```
echo "<pre>";
print_r($_POST);
echo "</pre>";
```

Additionally, axios allows you to send data in different formats. you can send a json for example like this:

```
axios.post('/sub/process.php', { id: "1", name:"blablah" }, {
    params: { action: "update-item" },
    headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
    baseURL: 'http://localhost',
}).then(data =>
    console.log(data)
).catch(err => {
    console.log(err)
    return null
})
```

In the PHP side, this can be accessed as follows:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"),true);
echo "<pre>";
print_r($data);
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 5):

**Using PHP std object**

Using PHP std object structure to get the variables of the post.

On the client:

```
axios.post(url, {id: 1 , Name:'My Name' }).then(function(response) {
    console.log(response.data);
});
```

On the server

```
$obj = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));   
$id = $obj->id;
$Name = $obj->Name;    

//test by returning the same values
$retObj=(object)["id"=>$id,"Name"=>$Name]
echo json_encode($retObj);
```

**Both jQuery and Axios using same PHP file**

if you have a file receiving post both from axios and jquery you may use:

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']==='POST' && empty($_POST)) {
   $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),true); 
}
```

to convert the Axios json-serialized posts to the $_POST array

Answer (score 2):

This code works on **browser/node** both today.
I think this is more practical.
I tested this code on node.js and passed the data variable to PHP8 using **$_POST['param1']** and it worked perfectly.

```
function axqs(d){
    let p = new URLSearchParams();
    Object.keys(d).forEach(function(key){
        p.append(key, this[key]);
    }, d);
    return p
}

let data = {
  'param1': 'value1',
  'param2': 'value2',
}

let p = axqs(data)
axios.post('/foo', p)
```

Answer (score -2):

Just wanted to share my insights, I was facing a similar problem and solved it by the following code set

JS

```
const instructions_str = {
  login: {
    "type": "devTool",
    "method": "devTool_login",
    "data": {
        "username": "test",
        "password": "Test@the9" 
    }
  },
  tables: {
    "type": "devTool",
    "method": "devTool_get_all_tables",
    "data": ""
  }
};

const body = {
    firstName: 'Fred',
    lastName: 'Flintstone',
    name: "John",
    time: "2pm",
    instructions : JSON.stringify(instructions_str)  
};

function decodeData(data) {
  const serializedData = []

  for (const k in data) {
    if (data[k]) {
      serializedData.push(`${k}=${encodeURIComponent(data[k])}`)
    }
  }

  return serializedData.join('&')
};

const body2 = decodeData(body);

axios.post('URL', body2)
  .then(response => {
    console.log("contextApi got it", response);
  }).catch(error => {
      console.log("contextApi error.response", error.response);
  });
```

PHP

```
// set content return type
header('Content-Type: application/json');

// Setting up some server access controls to allow people to get information
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods:  POST, GET');

// This way I can check and see what I sent
$postVars_array = $_POST ?? parse_str(file_get_contents("php://input"),$postVars_array) ?? [];
echo json_encode($postVars_array);
```

I also found this github page very helpful https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1195

Comment: Hello @Russell Moore to SO. Actually there are already good answers to this question and your answer is not giving a clear explanation. Moreover you should not post your logins/passwords in any public website, even if it's only for your development environment.