# PHP Post array empty on axios POST

Tags: javascript, php, axios

I'm trying out Vue 2.0 and axios and I've got a little issue.
When I try to send a post request using axios to my post.php file the $_POST array is always empty.

Post function:

```
doPost: function() {
  console.log("post in progress")
  axios.post('api/post.php', {
      title: 'foo',
      body: 'bar',
      userId: 1
  })
  .then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    console.log(response.data)
    this.filter = response.data
  })
  .catch(e => {
    this.errors.push(e)
  })
}
```

post.php

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded');


echo json_encode($_POST);
?>
```

The request is completed with status 200 but returns an empty object "[]"

Note: when I change the post endpoint to jsonplaceholder tool it works fine.

Comment: I posted something similar a while ago, maybe it'll help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457181/axios-posting-params-not-read-by-post

Comment: That Content-Type header makes absolutely no sense ...

Answer (score 18):

I think you can try this, it should be the data-type problem.

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append('title', 'foo');
data.append('body', 'bar');

axios.post('api/post.php', data)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response)
        console.log(response.data)
        this.filter = response.data
    })
    .catch(e => {
        this.errors.push(e)
});
```

Comment: This worked after i changed it to: `axios.post('api/post.php', data)`

Answer (score 11):

The data that is send with axios is not put into PHP's `$_POST`.
Instead, it is in the request body and most likely in json format.
To get it, try the following code:

```php
function getRequestDataBody()
{
    $body = file_get_contents('php://input');

    if (empty($body)) {
        return [];
    }

    // Parse json body and notify when error occurs
    $data = json_decode($body, true);
    if (json_last_error()) {
        trigger_error(json_last_error_msg());
        return [];
    }

    return $data;
}


$data = getRequestDataBody();
var_dump($data)
```

Or you could use `FormData` like the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 2):

For me the problem was that I was using http instead of https in the url. The server returned http status code Permanently moved (to the https site). A browser or command line client (curl) follow these redirects. My code did not. Solution was to use https in the url.

Comment: YES! That's it! Can't believe that all this hassle is because of an redirect. Thank you so much for mentioning this.