# How can I set to true $_POST['something'] using Axios or fetch API?

Tags: javascript, php, axios, fetch-api

I have a PHP file with multiple if statements where it checks if is set $_POST['something'] and returns specific data but when I try with ajax I can't get the data inside if statement because it isn't triggered to be true, here is what I am doing:
From index.php I am sending a request to users.php like this

```
<script>
axios.post('users.php').then(data=>console.log(data)); // this returns status 200 but data is empty
</script>
```

and the users.php looks like this

```
if(isset($_POST['getusers']))){ return users;}
```

How can I make this to true `isset($_POST['getusers'])` by sending the request using Axios or fetch API?
Note: There are other if statements inside the users.php file that's why I want to only get when a specific $_POST is set

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
axios.post('users.php',{ getusers: true }).then(function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
```

Comment: not working still returned data is empty :(

Comment: I updated my answer, please try now.

Comment: still the same, not working :(

Comment: Outside axios, can you confirm that if you do a POST towards 'users.php' with `"getusers" = true`  you are receiving the proper data you expect??

Comment: Also you could share your PHP code, as `if(isset($_POST['getusers']))){ return users;}
` on it's own is wrong, it has one additional `)` at the end ... are you validating somehow your PHP code? any actual errors on the backend log?

Comment: I found the solution thanks for trying to help me, this is the reference where I found the solution
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457181/axios-posting-params-not-read-by-post