# Axios image uploading with text

Tags: php, axios

I am using Axios for uploading images.

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="" method="post"> 
    <input type="text" id="name">
    <input type="files" multiple id="file">
    <button type="submit" onclick="submit_form()">Upload</button>
</form>
```

Axios code:

```
function submit_form(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   var form = new FormData();
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value;
   var image = document.getElementById("file");
   for (i = 0; i < image.files.length; i++) {                         
        let file = image.files[i];
       form.append("files[" + i + "]", file);
   }
   form.append("name", name);
   axios.post("ajax.php", form, {headers: {'content-type': 'multipart/form-data'}})
   .then((r) => {
      console.log(r);
    })
}
```

ajax.php:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"), true);
echo json_encode($data);
```

In the console it shows me `null`

If my PHP code is wrong, then can someone give a simple example?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios posting params not read by $\_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457181/axios-posting-params-not-read-by-post)

Comment: i think you can just use nomral $_POST; to send your data back