# Why is axios not sending the correct post data?

Tags: javascript, php, post, axios

Why is PHP saying "undefined index request"? The json format looks completely correct to me.

```
let json = JSON.stringify(
  { request:  "getUser" },
  { username: "test" }
);

const response = await axios.post('http://localhost/projects/serverFiles/index.php', json);
```

My PHP

```
<?php
    ini_set("log_errors", 1);

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
    header('Content-Type: application/json');
    
    echo print_r($_POST["request"]);
?>
```

Comment: Don't stringify the object. If you want to send as json you need to change axios content type and receive it differently in the php

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Axios posting params not read by $\_POST](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41457181/axios-posting-params-not-read-by-post)