# How to make a post request with Angular 4?

Tags: javascript, php, angular, typescript, post

I'm trying to make a post request with Angular 4 with this code to send lat and lng parameters:

```
let data = {lat: this.newLat, lng: this.newLng};

this.http.post(url, data)
  .map(response => response.json())
  .subscribe(getResponse => console.log(getResponse));
```

On the server side, I have the following php snippet:

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type");

if ( isset($_POST['lat'], $_POST['lng']) ) {
    $response['msg'] = 'ok';
} else {
    $response['msg'] = 'not ok';
}
echo json_encode($response);
```

The response from the server is unfortunately always `'not ok'`. Any ideas how to solve this? The `$_POST` variable is always an empty array

Comment: Any JS errors...?

Comment: No, I get the "not ok" message

Comment: Try `var_dump(file_get_contents("php://input"));` on PHP's side. See if you get any POST params in that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The PHP superglobal `$_POST`, only is supposed to wrap data that is either, `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` or `multipart/form-data-encoded`.

But if the `Content-Type` for request is anything else. You need to use:

```
$post = file_get_contents('php://input');
```

For more info look at this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8893792/2394254

Answer (score 0):

See [the documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http)

> If the data property of the request configuration object contains an object, serialize it into JSON format.

and

> $httpProvider.defaults.headers.post: (header defaults for POST requests)
>   Content-Type: application/json

---

Angular is encoding the data as JSON, and not one of the data formats which PHP will automatically parse into `$_POST`.

You need to [parse JSON as described in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19007851/19068).