# how use data in PHP from ajax form

Tags: php, ajax, forms

My javascript code:

```
function _(selector){ 
    return document.querySelector(selector); 
}

function submitForm(){
    var data = {
        name: _("#name").value,
        email: _("#email").value,
        message: _("#message").value
    }
    var output = JSON.stringify(data)
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
        ajax.open( "POST", "/PATH" );
        ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
        ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if(ajax.readyState == 4 && ajax.status == 200) {
                console.log('success')
            } else {
                console.log('fail')
            }

        }
        console.log(output)
        ajax.send(output);

}
```

When im trying do this with static data,it's work :

```
<?php
    $name = "mateusz";
    $to = "kaawkamateusz@gmail.com";
    $subject = "kucharz";
    $message = "message";
    mail($to, $subject, $message);
?>
```

but, on example :

```
$name = $_POST["name"];
```

doesn't work.

Im trying use JSON  but again, idk how get value from AJAX form in PHP.

Im never use PHP before, need help :)

EDIT

print_r show :

```
Array
(
    [{"name":"asd","email":"asd@gmail_com","message":"12"}] => 
)
```

Comment: Just try without `sringify`, `var output = data;`

Comment: Still doesn't work, thanks for asnwer

Comment: What does the $_POST array look like? You can examine the structure and contents of the array in PHP with print_r().

Comment: Thank you, i update post with print_r results :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> ```
> ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
> ```

You say you are sending URL encoded form data …

> ```
> var output = JSON.stringify(data)
> ```

… but your data is JSON encoded.

---

To URL form encode it [use `URLSearchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams/URLSearchParams).

```js
var data = {
  name: "Example Name",
  email: "example@example.com",
  message: "This is a message"
}


var output = new URLSearchParams(data);
console.log(output.toString());
```

Note [limited browser support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=urlsearchparams). Consider using a [polyfill](https://github.com/jerrybendy/url-search-params-polyfill).

---

Alternatively, set the correct content type for JSON and [rewrite the PHP since JSON is not supported for `$_POST`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19004783/reading-json-post-using-php).

Comment: Thank you very much, im fighting with this 3 days :)